# Twilio: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid Access Token

Tags: twilio

I'm having an odd problem trying to use Twilio's sync service. The initial call of `syncClient = new Twilio.Sync.Client(tokenResponse, { logLevel: 'trace' });` response with successful connection messages. But when I call `syncClient.document('DealerMap').then(function(doc) {` I get a handshake error `twilio-sync.min.js:100 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid Access Token` How can I have an invalid access token if the client accepted it?

Here's what my token looks like: 
Header:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS256",
  "cty": "twilio-fpa;v=1"
}
```

Body:

```
{
  "sub": "ACxxx",
  "iss": "SKxxx",
  "exp": 1497527958,
  "nbf": 1497441558,
  "grants": {
    "identity": "Usernamexxx",
    "data_sync": {
      "service_sid": "ISxxx"
    }
  },
  "jti": "SKxxx"
}
```

jwt.io verifies my secret is correct.

Comment: Are you setting a ttl on your token? Can you inspect a token in http://jwt.io and share the result?

Comment: I've added that. I did not set a ttl; but adding it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: @philnash The other odd thing is `syncClient.document('Sample').then(function(doc) {` returns `GET https://cds.twilio.com/v3/Documents/Sample 401 (Unauthorized)`  Maybe I'm calling the document wrong?

Comment: Was that a recently generated token? Because I calculated the `exp` time as 2017-06-15 11:59:18 UTC. Which is right out of date. Is the clock on your machine set correctly?

Comment: @philnash I must have pasted an old token by mistake. The time for a recent one shows `"exp": 1498143718,
  "nbf": 1498057318,`, GMT: Wednesday, June 21, 2017 3:01:58 PM - Thursday, June 22, 2017 3:01:58 PM

Comment: I also tried changing it to just use an hour between the nbf and exp

Comment: Do you have a free or upgraded account?

Comment: @philnash It's upgraded